# I'm getting this error "the "path" argument must be of type string. receved an instance of array" when i try to upload more than 2 img to cloudinary

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, mern, cloudinary

This is my Create product code.I Thought it was multiple issue in frontend input tag but sadly it was not the issue. The problem is quantity of images not their size. The project is created using MERN.

It works normally when i upload 1 or 2 images but when i upload three or more  it gives me this error.[Here is the image of the error i am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XI3Pd.png)

On console i am getting this error "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)"

The error says the "path" argument must be of type string. Recieved an instance of array

```
exports.createProduct = catchAsyncError(async (req, res, next) => {
  let images = [];

  if (typeof req.body.images === "string") {
    images.push(req.body.images);
  } else {
    images = req.body.images;
  }

  const imagesLinks = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    const result = await cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload(images[i], {
      folder: "products",
    });

    imagesLinks.push({
      public_id: result.public_id,
      url: result.secure_url,
    });
  }

  req.body.images = imagesLinks;
  req.body.user = req.user.id;

  const product = await Product.create(req.body);

  res.status(201).json({
    success: true,
    product,
  });
});
```

Comment: Please add the full error as text in the question

Comment: Try logging some values; worth checking `req.body.images` before the if and `images` after. May also be worth enforcing the type/shape of the data being passed to this so you're not trying to handle multiple formats.

Comment: Additionally, you may check out the file parameter definition for the Upload API upload method as described in this [document](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_upload_api_reference#upload:~:text=Description-,file,-String).